# Why can't I change an image's width using this function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the width of the image to 200px (fixed size) only if the image width is greater than 200px, else i want to leave its original width.

**now below code works:**

```
<img src="../images/browse-files.png"  style="width:200px" onload="var img = new Image(); img.src = this.src; if(img.width <= 680){ var imgW= '680' + 'px' ; this.style.width =imgW;} "/>
```

**But below code doesn't:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
resize(){
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = this.src; 
    if(img.width <= 680){ 
        var imgW= '680' + 'px' ; 
        this.style.width = imgW;
    }
return this.style.width;                            
}
</script>

<img src="../images/browse-files.png"  style="width:200px" onload="return resize() "/>
```

I would like to know what i am doing wrong with the last method. I prefer the last methose cos i want to include all the JavaScript functions on one .js page.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My mistake for last extra </script> tag at the bottom. Ill delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the `onload` event onto an image element like that, it has to go on the instance of `Image`. Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BffAn/1/) (or reference code below) to get a good start. I first created an instance of `Image` so that I could detect when it loads. Then, `onload` of the image, check and see if the size is greater than 200. If it is, get the original image **element**, *not the instance of `Image`*, and resize it.

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");

var img = new Image();
    img.src = image.src;

img.onload = function(){
    if (img.width > 200) {
        image.style.width = "200px";
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're using `parseInt()` don't forget the radix: [`parseInt(variable, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to specify the base and minimise the potential for weirdness.

Comment: @DavidThomas You're right, but I didn't realize that the `parseInt()` was still in there. I was just playing around with something before. Updated without `parseInt()`.

Comment: @Nile Thanks a lot. It works perfect. I would vote up for you but my rep is 12, i need 15 to vote.

Comment: @printfmyname I'm glad to help. Select this as an answer by clicking the bordered checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't declaring the function properly.

```
function resize(){
  var img = new Image(); 
  img.src = this.src; 
  if(img.width <= 680){ 
    ...
  }
}
```